# Find child element of an element in an array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple checkboxes, if one of them is checked then I want to perform a task on a heading in their respective `div`. The issue is: When one of the boxes is checked, it performs the task for both divs.

```
var showColor = function() {
    if ($('div').find('.check1, .check2').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).siblings('.heading').css("color", "pink");
    } else if ($(".check1, .check2").is(":not(:checked)")) {
        $(this).siblings(".heading").removeAttr('style');
    }
};
```

Any idea how I could do it?

Comment: Show us the corresponding HTML code

Comment: Seeing the corresponding HTML markup would be helpful, to say the least

Comment: You need to reverse your logic by hooking a `change` event to the checkboxes themselves, then use DOM traversal to find the `closest()` parent div. We can give you an example of how to do this, but we need to see your HTML first.

Comment: Yes, please provide a minimum working example, otherwise it is hard to help you.